# Use callback or promise to make async code to work like sync in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

My nodejs api function:

```
exports.userSignup = (req, res) => {
  const home = {
    address: req.body.name,
    phoneno: req.body.code,
  };
  Home.create(home)
    .then((data) => {
      createUser()
        // i want to complete the above createUser() function fully then only i need to move to this below then function

        .then(() => {
          const loginDetails = {
            username: 'stackoverflow',
          };
          User.create(loginDetails)
            .then((data) => {
              return res.status(200).send(data);
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log('error while create schema:', err);
            });
        });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err:', err);
    });
};
```

My createUser function code:

```
const createUser = () => {
  Home.findAll({
    raw: true,
  }).then((data) => {
    data.forEach((client) => {
      postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => {
        Object.keys(postgresDB.models).forEach((currentItem) => {
          postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
        });
        console.log('Postgres schema created');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Warning:', err.message);
  });
};
createUser();
```

But this one is working as asynchronous,

How to make this using promise resolve reject or callback?

See my code, i made a comment which needs to work first,

I tried with async await but not working!

Comment: Updated my answer. Didn't notice you were executing asynchronous function calls within a for loop. Snippet should work.

Comment: No async code will ever work synchronously. You need to adapt your `forEach` loop

Answer (score 2):

In order for promise chaining to work, you have to return a promise for any asynchronous functions or else it won't wait. You're also making another asynchronous call for each client you iterate through. In order to deal with multiple promises at once, you need to push each promise into an array and pass it to `Promise.all`. Here's a snippet that should work.

```
const createUser = () => {
  return Home.findAll({
    raw: true,
  }).then((data) => {
    const promises = [];
    data.forEach((client) => {
      promises.push(
        postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => {
          Object.keys(postgresDB.models).forEach((currentItem) => {
             postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
             console.log('Postgres schema created');
          })
        })
      );
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Warning:', err.message);
  });
};
```

Comment: @MohamedSameer Promises are a newer addition to JavaScript and callbacks were the old way of dealing with asynchronous code before Promises were added to the language spec. I recommend using promises and async await as opposed to callbacks when possible as it keeps code a bit cleaner; however, older APIs use callbacks so you're forced to use them.

Comment: I used your code, still its works as async, my below code works before!

Comment: @MohamedSameer My apologies. I malformed the code a bit due to the nesting on accident. Try my edited version.

Comment: Ok sure wait let me check

Comment: @MohamedSameer Any luck?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173663/discussion-between-jake-miller-and-mohamed-sameer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the synchronous data.forEach() call inside the createUser function which doesn't wait for the async createSchema calls to finish before returning.
You can fix this by using an async implementation of forEach function or by using Promise.all()

Here's a piece of code that might work for you:

```js
const createUser = () => {
  return Home.findAll({
    raw: true
  }).then((data) => Promise.all(
    data.map((client) => postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() =>
      Promise.all(Object.keys(postgresDB.models).map((currentItem) =>
        postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync()
      ))
    ))
  ))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Warning:', err.message);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If [async/await](http://thecodebarbarian.com/common-async-await-design-patterns-in-node.js.html) doesn't quite work for you, just use promise chaining. It's super painful to see people just write callback based code with promises and forget that you can chain promises by returning a promise from the `onFulfilled()` parameter to `then()`:

```
const createUser = () => {
  return Home.findAll({ raw: true }).
    then(data => {
      return Promise.all(data.map(client => postgresDB.createSchema(client.code)));
    }).
    then(() => {
      const keys = Object.keys(postgresDBModels);
      return Promise.all(keys.map(currentItem => {
        return postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
      }));
    }).
    then(() => console.log('Postgres schema created')).
    catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
createUser();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use async and await in createUser function. You can alter your function by Using promise, We can able to either resolve or reject.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I tried this, now also the code which is in below api, works first ! the createUser function does not completed yet , but the exports api function "then" function working.

Comment: This example is so wrong on so many levels. The biggest issue is that, since `forEach()` doesn't return a promise, `await forEach(fn)` doesn't actually pause until `fn` is done, see http://thecodebarbarian.com/basic-functional-programming-with-async-await#motivation-and-for-each. Also, `await fn().then(async() => { foo(); });` is a horrible anti-pattern that removes  any readability benefit of using async/await. Use `await fn(); foo();`

Comment: @vkarpov15, Thanks. Actually I made a mistake. forEach doesn't actually pause until fn is done since forEach already an asynchronous function.